# Functionality of sleep() method in rails but in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

In rails, you can call `sleep 5` server side to tell the server to wait 5 seconds.  Once the time has elapsed, it will continue executing the code.

What is the conventional way to do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is built on PHP, and PHP has its own [sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function.

From the documentation:

```
<?php

// current time
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

// wake up !
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
```

Output:

> 05:31:23
>
> 05:31:33